# Reactjs - Why the callback method of a component is called when its state changes?

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, why is the method `handleColumnAdded` called when I click on the "Add line" button?

I just want to give access to a method of my component from the `Line`  component.

```
addLine(){
  var lineArray = this.state.lines;
  var line = {id:(lineArray.length+1),text:'hello'};
  lineArray.push(line);
  this.setState({
    lines : lineArray
  });
}
handleColumnAdded(){
  console.log("handleColumnAdded");
}
render() {
  var me = this;

    var lines = this.state.lines.map(function(line) {
        return (
            <Line key={line.id} data={line} onColumnAdded={me.handleColumnAdded()}/>
        );
    });

  return (
    <div>          
      <div>
          {lines}
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.addLine.bind(this)}>Add line</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 <Line key={line.id} data={line} onColumnAdded={me.handleColumnAdded()}/>
```

to this

```
 <Line key={line.id} data={line} onColumnAdded={me.handleColumnAdded}/>
```

Reason:

`onColumnAdded` expects a function, but you are invoking the function when you include `()`. When you do that, the function gets invoked immediately, rather than being invoked in an eventful manner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. It was a syntax error